# Who governed while Alexander the Great was away conquering Asia?

Tags: ancient-greece, government, alexander-the-great, macedon

I was just watching a video that mentions [Alexander the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_the_Great) at the edges of his [empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macedonia_(ancient_kingdom)), but then I was wondering who was governing back home while he was gone, I mean it took forever to travel back then so, there must have been someone or a body governing.

Comment: Please note than countries were much less centralized back then, even those which didn't span continents. Even just inside Macedonia/Greece, most cities and territories had to be governed by local governors, as communication was slow even without leaving the peninsula. There was a whole hierarchy of regional rulers who had quite a good local autonomy.

Answer (score 36):

Alexander left [Antipater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipater) in charge in Macedonia/Greece while he was off conquering. Antipater had previously served Alexander's father, Phillip II, and had also previously served as regent for Alexander when he was fighting in Thrace, prior to the invasion of the Persian empire.

I believe Antipater also governed Greece after Alexander's death and subsequent [Wars of the Diadochi.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wars_of_the_Diadochi)

[Source](https://www.britannica.com/biography/Alexander-the-Great)

Answer (score -3):

I believe Alexander The Great's Central/Administrative Government was located in the Egyptian city of Memphis. The city of Alexandria-(in Northern Egypt), was akin to a royal figurehead city which was more ceremonial in nature versus the more pragmatic-(day to day) bureaucratically administered city of Memphis.

(After Alexander's passing, the city of Alexandria would become the Capital of Ptolemaic Egypt, as well the Hellenistic era's most important city).

Interestingly, Alexander did not choose any city within Greece or Anatolia-(present-day Turkey) to serve as either the Ceremonial or Administrative Capital of his expansive empire; nor did Alexander choose to establish his Capital city in the defeated imperial city of Persepolis in Persia-(present-day Iran).  Yet, the land of Egypt-(more specifically, the cities of Alexandria and Memphis), would become the epicenters of imperial power during his brief reign.

Comment: 1. I am not sure how this is suppose to answer the question about administration of Macedonia and Greece. 2. AFAIU, Alexander founded Alexandria of Egypt but didn't use it as a capital for his empire, that would rather be Susa or Babylon.

Comment: A few points of clarification:

Comment: 1.  While it is a short answer, it certainly does answer the question about the administration of his empire-(which does not solely focus on "the administration of Macedonia and Greece").

Comment: 2. As I had clearly stated in my answer, the city of Alexandria, during Alexander's time, was more of a "ceremonial city", versus an administrative city.  During his reign, Alexander's administrative capital city, was neither located in Susa, nor was it located Babylon....it was located in the Egyptian city of Memphis.

Comment: 1. It is unclear what the OP means with "back home". I interpreted this as Macedonia, but maybe I'm wrong and they mean "in the heart of the Empire". In any case, I'm pretty sure Alexander didn't consider Memphis as "back home"... Also, the OP asks "who", and this answer doesn't adress this. 2. The empire being administered from Memphis (and the existence of a central gvt at all) is a very strong claim that would need to be backed with references.

Comment: Keep in mind that even though Egypt and Memphis, in particular, were foreign places, they became a new "home" for Alexander, as well as for a small, but burgeoning Greek community.  However, my guess is that judging from the question asked, the questioner may not necessarily have been aware of Alexander's adopted "home".....which was Egypt.

Comment: Alexander was only in Egypt for about 4 months in his life, between December 332BCE and Spring 331BCE, when he went back east to fight Persia. Why you call it his "adopted home" escapes me.

Comment: Egypt was his "adopted home" because it was the land/country that would serve and function as the ceremonial and administrative capital of his empire. Whether he spent 4 days, 4 months or 4 years within Egypt proper, is irrelevant.  The fact that Alexander deliberately chose Egypt as the Central location of his imperial capital indicates that he believed that Egypt, was not just another country that was part of his imperial campaign; but rather, a unique land in terms of its geopolitical, commercial, cultural and even...its religious/divine significance.....in other words...his "adopted home".

Comment: Alexander could have selected Pella or Aigai-(present-day Vergina) in Northern Greece-(which were both the Royal Capitals of Macedonia) or he could have selected any major city or town within Greece or Anatolia-(present-day Turkey) to serve as his administrative and ceremonial Capital.  Alexander, could have converted the imperial and Royal capital of Persepolis in Persia-(present-day Iran), into his administrative and ceremonial capital.  Yet, Alexander chose Egypt, to serve as his administrative and ceremonial Capitals... .essentially, turning Egypt into an adopted home.

Comment: *The fact that Alexander deliberately chose Egypt as the Central location of his imperial capital* is **not** an historical fact unless you can provide some references backing it.

Comment: I think we have exhausted this topic.......I stand by my answer.

Comment: I agree we have exhausted the discussion since you don't plan to improve your unsourced answer. (-1)

Comment: Okay.....whatever.